# How to define os and osversion for a salt state?

Tags: salt-stack

I have `top.sls`:

```
base:
  '*':
    - core

  'os:Windows':
    - match: grain
    - repos.windows
```

How can I define not only `os:Windows` but also `osrelease:10`?

I have tried `'os:Windows,osrelease:10'` but that doesn't work.

Please note: In this particular case, I could use `'osfullname:Microsoft Windows 10*'`, however I wish to know how to combine two items such as `os` and `osrelease`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `compound` matching:

```
  'G@os:Windows and G@osrelease:10':
    - match: compound
    - repos.windows
```

You can do fancy matches with this technique, mixing grains and pillar data, for example.

Documentation: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html